# C++ Heart, Spades, Clubs, Diamonds characters not showing up

Tags: unicode, ascii

I need to create a card game for a school assignment and I am trying to display the heart, diamonds, spades, and clubs symbols in the output.

The teacher told us to use char(3), char(4), etc but the output shows a question mark. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10.

I am not too familiar with Unicode or ASCII stuff, if anyone could help me out, I still have 3 days to submit this assignment!! I'm a beginner

Thank you

//For COMP 218 Section EC (Winter 2017) - Concordia University

```
cout << char(3) << char(4) << char(5) << char(6) << char(3) << char(4) << char(5) << char(6) << char(3) << char(4) << char(5) << char(6) << endl
    << "\t \t Welcome to Shawn's Card Dealing Program" << endl
    << char(3) << char(4) << char(5) << char(6) << char(3) << char(4) << char(5) << char(6) << char(3) << char(4) << char(5) << char(6);

cout << "RULES: \nTwo cards are dealt at a time. They are then compared. \nSince there are two decks of cards, you may have identital cards. \nI will tell you if they are the same or not" << endl
    << "or if they just have the same suit or rank. \nOnce I finish comparing the two cards, they are returned to the deck, the deck is reshuffled and two more cards are dealt. \n \n" << endl
    << "So how many pairs shall I deal? (1 to 15 max): \n > ";

while (!valid)
{
    valid = true;

    cin >> loops;

    if (cin.fail() || loops < 1 || loops > 15)
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Please enter an integer between 1 and 15:" << endl << "> ";
        valid = false;
    }

}

int pairCount = loops;

do
{
    card1.genRandom();
    card2.genRandom();


    cout << "Pair " << setw(2) << pairCount - loops + 1 << " - ";

    card1.printCard();
    card2.printCard();
    cout << endl;

    if (card1.sameCard(card2) == true)
    {
        cout << "same card" << endl;
        ident += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (card1.sameSuit(card2) == true)
        {
            cout << "same suit" << endl;
            sameSuit +=1;
        }
        if (card1.sameRank(card2) == true)
        {
            cout << "same rank" << endl;
            sameRank += 1;
        }
        if (card1.sameRank(card2) == false && card1.sameSuit(card2) == false)
        {
            cout << "both different" << endl;
            different +=1;
        }
    }

    loops -= 1;
} while (loops > 0);

cout << "Identical: " << ident << endl;
cout << "Same Suit: " << sameSuit << endl;
cout << "Same Rank: " << sameRank << endl;
cout << "Both different: " << different << endl;
```

}

Comment: You are exercising your ability to solve problems, it doesn't matter what it looks like.  Comes pretty handy once somebody starts paying you good money for it.  "clubs" means the exact same thing as "♣", so no reason to get stuck on this.  Figuring out how to configure the console so it uses the correct font and codepage, that can wait for other day and already covered by many existing questions here.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not using ASCII and have actually been instructed to use a different encoding as evidenced by the requirement for playing card suit characters, which are not in the ASCII character set. (Pretty much any mention of ASCII without a reference to a specification is very suspect.)

You could be using CP437 (go `chcp` in your command prompt.) CP437 is one of the encodings where 3,4,5,6 are the playing card suits. It's possible that your system is conveniently set up with a command prompt encoding more useful for French. If so, you could just run `chcp 437` each time you open a command prompt for this program.

For this to work, your command prompt also has to set for a font that supports the characters. I think the vast majority of fonts do support the playing card suit characters so this probably isn't an issue.

Comment: Thank you Tom. Yes, my computer is in French and so is the command prompt. When I enter ''chcp'' in CMD, it returns (in French): Active code page: 437.

I still have no clue what this is, but at this point, I'll just write out the words ''Hearts, Clubs, ... '' instead. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Glad to help. @Hans is correct with the praise and each of his other points. I suggest you check in to see if it's expected that you spend time on issues that are presumably outside the scope of the assignment.